# How to express "smth has been leaking and is almost empty" in a shorter way?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Here is a situation:

> A bottle has been leaking water so it is almost empty.

How can I express the situation without using the second part of the sentence (without "so it is almost empty")? What is the shorter sentence for it? I know "to eat up smth" means to eat everything, "to take smb captive" means to force smb to be captive. Do you say "to leak up" or "to leak empty" to express the mentioned situation? I need something idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The water has "leaked away".

> Oh no, there must have been a hole in my bottle and the water has leaked away.  What am I going to drink?

If you want to say that there a little left you might use

> Almost all the water has leaked out of the bottle

(as suggested by Kate)

Comment: The water has leaked away means the bottle is empty, right? Can I say "the bottle has almost leaked all the water" or "all the water has almost leaked out of/from the bottle"?

Comment: 'Almost all the water has leaked out of the bottle.'